# Positive definite - Inverse of sparse symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a matrix $P\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that at most $m<n$ elements of each column are non zero and $P$ is symmetric. I would like to find the  sufficient condition(s) such that $P^{-1}$ is positive definite. Given the positions of non zero elements in $P$ what are their values such that $P$ is positive definite.

Comment: do you need $P^{-1}$ to be sparse? Otherwise it is trivial...

Comment: I need specific elements of $P$ to be non zero, Jacobi Rotations on a positive definite diagonal matrix might work as user251257 said.

Answer (score 2):

If $P$ is an invertible real symmetric matrix, $P^{-1}$ is positive definite iff $P$ is positive definite.  There are many equivalent conditions to positive definiteness.

Comment: That is true but not sufficient for the sparsity . So How do I generate a positive definite sparse symmetric matrix?

Comment: @Cauchy: Google is your friend. Apply random [Jacobi Rotations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_rotation) on a positive definite diagonal matrix...